# What are developers their expectations when receiving a JSON response from a server

Tags: json

I have java library that runs webservices and these return a response in XML. The webservices all revolve around giving a list of details about items. Recently, changes were made to allow the services to return JSON by simply converting the XML to JSON. When looking at the responses, I saw they're not as easy to parse as I thought. For example, a webservice that returns details about items.

If there are no items, the returned JSON is as follows:

```
{"ItemResponse":""}
```

If there is 1 item, the response is as follows (now itemResponse has a object as value instead of a string):

```
{"ItemResponse":{"Items":{"Name":"Item1","Cost":"$5"}}}
```

If there two or more items, the response is (now items has an array as value instead of an object):

```
{"ItemResponse":{"Items":[{"Name":"Item1","Cost":"$5"},{"Name":"Item2","Cost":"$3"}]}}
```

To parse these you need several if/else which I think are clunky.

Would it be an improvement if the responses were:

- 0 items: []
- 1 item: [{"Name":"Item1","Cost":"$5"}]
- 2 items: [{"Name":"Item1","Cost":"$5"},{"Name":"Item2","Cost":"$3"}]

This way there is always an array, and it contains the itemdata. An extra wrapper object is possible:

- 0 items: {"Items":[]}
- 1 item: {"Items":[{"Name":"Item1","Cost":"$5"}]}
- 2 items: {"Items":[{"Name":"Item1","Cost":"$5"},{"Name":"Item2","Cost":"$3"}]}

I'm not experienced in JSON so my question is, if you were a developer having to use these webservices, how would you expect the JSON resonse to be formatted? Is it better to always return a consistent array, even if there are no items or is this usually not important? Or is an array not enough and do you really expect a wrapper object around the array?

What are conventions/standards regarding this?

Comment: The important thing is that you document the format of the output. And you'll find it much easier to document it (and for users to handle it) if you do indeed use a consistent format, which would be to always have an array. I would go for the second version, as it allows you to add different types of data (including errors!)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't switch result types, always return an array if there are more items possible. Do not mix, for 1 item an object for more an array. That's not a good idea.

Another best practise is that you should version your API. Use something like `yoursite.com/api/v1/endpoint`. If you don't do this and you change the response of your API. All your client apps will break. So keep this in mind together with documentation. (I've seen this happen a lot in the past..)

As a developer I personally like your second approach, but again it's a preference. There is no standard for this.

Comment: There's no version yet, I'm still developing it (but I'll keep the tip in mind, thanks). I was just curious as to how json is usually formatted. My guts told me the same as your guts: keep it consistent.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons to use json:

- much more dense and compact: thus data sent is less
- in javascript you can directly access those properties without parsing anything. this means you could convert it into an object read the attributes (often used for AJAX)
- also in java you usually don't need to parse the json by yourself - there are several nice libs like www.json.org/java/index.html
- if you need to know how json is build ... use google ... there tons of infos.

To your actual questions:

- for webservices you often could choose between xml and json as a "consumer" try:
  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json
  and
  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml
- there is no need to format json visually - is it not meant for reading like xml
- if your response doesn't have a result, json-service often still is giving a response text - look again at the upper google map links - those are including a response status which makes sense as it is a service.

Nevertheless it's the question if it is worth converting from xml to json if there isn't a specific requirement. As Dieter mentioned: it depends on who is already using this service and how they are consumed ... which means the surrounding environment is very important.

Comment: Nobody is using it yet, I'm trying to make it in such a way that people can and will use it - with minimal effort on their part. Are you saying that it is not important in which of the three manners described in my question the JSON is formatted and that they are all equally usable for developers?